# Working with Amazon Kinesis from client JavaScript in a secure way

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I would like to use Amazon JavaScript SDK to send data from my webpage (using JavaScript) to Amazon Kinesis. If I open this functionality, is there a way to prevent everyone on the world from just sending me junk data?

[Amazon documentation for Kinesis JS client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Kinesis.html)

Comment: KCL is for consuming the data in the Kinesis stream. You want to use the Javascript SDK. Doesn't answer your question, just want to make sure you don't get confused during implementation.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel How did it go for opening kinesis to world ? planning to do the same

Comment: @GauravShah - In the end we dropped the Kinesis approach and opened a server-farm of Jetty server to filter the incoming data and push it into Rabbit Exchanges. The Kinesis was missing some features we needed like filtering the data, but also have many more consumers of data than producers

Comment: @RoeeGavirel Thank you for your information. We are planning to go with Kinesis + lambda + Kinesis . Th e lambda inbetween would do the filtering etc

Comment: @GauravShah that sound like a fare approach, if you'll have the time I would love to hear if it worked for you.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel would definitely share if we use that, kinesis doesn't seem to even have a ip blocking mechanism, that throws off, will update you in a week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like there's no way to stop people from making requests to your REST service, there's no way to prevent the calls from being made. You can require authentication to get an access token to write to the stream, but a malicious person would just authenticate. I think you have to think about dealing with the possibility of junk data during consumption, not preventing writing. Luckily Kinesis can be scaled to handle any load you throw at it.